# Changing RESTSharp POST code to .NET HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, postman, dotnet-httpclient, restsharp

I'm struggling a bit with a RestSharp POST request which I need to change to use HttpClient instead. It's quite a special case where I need to send some HTML markup to [Memsource](https://memsource.com) to create a new translation job. I've got it working in Postman where I am able to get the code example as a RestSharp request, but in my codebase, I'm using HttpClient.

The RestSharp code example in Postman looks like this:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://cloud.memsource.com/web/api2/v1/projects/<myProjectId>/jobs?token=<myAuthToken>");
client.Timeout = -1;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"translation.html\"");
request.AddHeader("Memsource", "{\"targetLangs\": [\"da\", \"de\", \"de-AT\", \"de-BE\"]}");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

request.AddParameter("application/octet-stream", "<!doctype html>\r\n<html lang=\"en\">\r\n<head>\r\n  
<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\r\n  <title>My page</title>\r\n  <meta name=\"viewport\" 
content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n\t<h1>My page</h1>\r\n\t<p>This is a paragraph<br />That needs to be translated</p>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>",  ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

My attempt with HttpClient is currently this:

```
string previewMarkup = "" // omitted markup for readability in this post

var targetLangs = new { targetLangs = new[] { "da", "de", "de-AT", "de-BE" } };
string targetLanguagesParamJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(targetLangs);

HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(previewMarkup, Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

httpContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"translation.html\"");
httpContent.Headers.Add("Memsource", targetLanguagesParamJson);
httpContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);

HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://cloud.memsource.com/web/api2/v1/projects/<myProjectId>/jobs?token=<myAuthToken>", httpContent, cancellationToken);
```

I keep getting the following error: `The format of value 'filename="translations.html"' is invalid.`

Does anyone know, what I might be missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Content-Disposition is a *response* header not a *request* header so it makes no sense to me that it would be included in a request

Comment: @AdamStraughan you and me both, but not according to the Memsource API documentation for creating translation jobs: https://cloud.memsource.com/web/docs/api#operation/createJob :-/

Comment: You can recreate your issue with `new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("filename=\"translation.html\"");` you may be able to debug that and see what's happening